# Using Tufte-LaTeX sfsidenotes option, how do I use the normal title style and how do I use sans-serif math in the side notes?

Tags: tufte, sans-serif

I'm using the Tufte Handout package's `sfsidenotes` option, which displays the sidenotes in a sans-serif font. Unfortunately, it also displays the title in sans-serif font. So it displays the first image instead of the second (what you would get without the `sfsidenotes` option).[image]

instead of this

[image: What I want.]

Secondly, I am using `kpfonts` package that has support for math fonts. Yet the math in the sidenotes comes in a serif font.
[image]

So my questions are:

1. How do I alter the title style in this document class separately?
2. How do I have the math in the sidenotes follow the same style as the text, that is how do I use the sans-serif in the sidenotes?